# Url rewriting breaks web api calls

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, angular-ui-router, asp.net-web-api

In my angularjs application, I used UI.Router and try to add the html 5 mode to remove the # from URL, I copy the settings from github for ui router, there is a section [Azure IIS Rewrites settings](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions), here is the settings

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Everything works properly even the page refresh but it breaks my Web API calls.

When I call any get method on the web api, it always returns the index.html content. If try to call any post method it gives error:

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Any help to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I solve it by adding one more patter to skip

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
```

Now it is working

Comment: Hey, how did you manage to do this? Are you hosting both your web front end app and webapi within the same application pool and project folder structure in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Read about how IIS rewrite works. The condition section i believe can be augmented with additional conditions which can ignore some url patterns such as patterns which have `/api` in it. 
If you look at the last example from this blog http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/#asp-net
There is a condition added to skip `.axd`, something similar can be done for API urls too.

`<add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="/API/" />`

Though I am not sure if the above pattern will work. You need to experiment with it and maybe post the right pattern to use here.